# Error while kriging within QGIS (R script)

Tags: qgis, r

I am trying to incorporate an R script within QGIS and have some problems with kriging interpolation. Here is my code :

```
G_STRUCT=gstat(NULL, id="OBS", formula=field~1, data=PointOrig, model=v_fit)
coordinates(PointOrig)=c('X','Y')
proj4string(PointOrig)=CRS(proj4string(PointGrid))
krige=predict(G_STRUCT, PointGrid)
```

NB : both PointOrig and PointGrid are point vector layers.

When I run the code, I get this error :

```
Error in bbox(dataLst[[1]]$data) : object not a >= 2-column array
Calls: predict ... predict.gstat -> getMaxDist -> apply -> bbox -> bbox
```

I tested the script under R Studio and it works well.

Comment: Your code here is not complete if it is the R-script called in QGIS. You need to give us the header. I guess `PointGrid` is not a 2-column matrix. Do you ask for a point shapefile in your QGIS app ? In this case, you will need to convert it to be used in `predict` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed error by setting `coordinates` and `proj4string` before G_STRUCT.

```
coordinates(PointOrig)=c('X','Y')
proj4string(PointOrig)=CRS(proj4string(PointGrid))
G_STRUCT=gstat(NULL, id="OBS", formula=field~1, data=PointOrig, model=v_fit)
krige=predict(G_STRUCT, PointGrid)
```

It's working now.